# Spring JPA performance with Pageable and Example

Tags: spring, jpa

Using the following `findAll` method

```java
public interface QueryByExampleExecutor<T> {
   <S extends T> Page<S> findAll(Example<S> example, Pageable pageable); 
   ...
}
```

querying a table containing millions records. The `Pageable` object containing a `Sort` directive.

Despite the pagination and indexes created in the table, the query take about 15s to complete.

Wondering if this is due to the Example parameter (which contains about 20 parameters) and if there is a way to improve the performance ?

Comment: Re-run the method with Hibernate's `show-sql` enabled and analyze the printed query. The actual query might differ from the expected one.

Comment: Just log the sql statement can be a big help.  Let's see how hibernate convert the pager.